# When is it better to use npz files instead of csv?

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I'm looking at some machine learning/forecasting code using Keras, and the input data sets are stored in npz files instead of the usual csv format.

Why would the authors go with this format instead of csv? What advantages does it have?

Comment: see https://kite.com/python/docs/numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile

Comment: `csv` is restricted to 2d with text compatible elements (dtype).  `npz` is an archive of `npy` files, thus has multiple arrays.  Generally it will be faster, but it's not usable by other languages.

Answer (score 1):

From https://kite.com/python/docs/numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile

> A dictionary-like object with lazy-loading of files in the zipped archive provided on construction.

So, it is a zipped archive (smaller size than CSV on the disk, more than one file can be stored) and files can be loaded from disk only when needed (in CSV, when you only need 1 column, you still have to read whole file to parse it).

=> advantages are: performance and more features

Comment: Actually an `npz` is not necessarily compressed.  It can be created with either `np.savez` or `np.savez_compressed`.  More significantly is the fact that the individual files in the archive are `npy` files, as created with `np.save`.  Most of the data in such a file is a byte copy of the data buffer of the array.  That's likely to be more compact than a string formatted version of the same data.  It should also load faster.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the expected usage. If a file is expected to have broad use cases including direct access from an ordinary client machines, then csv is fine because it can be directly loaded in Excel or LibreOffice calc which are widely deployed. But it is just an good old text file with no indexes nor any additional feature.

On the other hand is a file is only expected to be used by data scientists or generally speaking numpy aware users, then npz is a much better choice because of the additional features (compression, lazy loading, etc.)

Long story made short, you exchange a larger audience for higher features.